# Need help restoring a corrupted folder

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, data-recovery, mbr, corruption

I have a mechanical hard drive that I was trying to access files on. I bought a cheap SATA to USB adapter. Said adapter was underpowered, and I could hear the platter revving up and down. I made the mistake of clicking on a file in the home folder while this was happening. After this, my home folder was replaced with a text file labeled "home" [image: screenshot of subdirectory with corrupted folder][image: Screenshot of "home" text file when opened]

Is there a way I can recover files on drive from vanished folder? Its formated as ext4. It was from an old Ubuntu installation. I would like to restore the function of the text file so that maybe it becomes an active folder again. If not, I'm willing to use some type of recovery software. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I included a screenshot of the sub-directory with the corrupted folder circled in red. I also included a screenshot of the text that appears when opening text file titled "home".

Answer (score 1):

1. Unmount the partition
2. Create a full image of the partition in question just in case, e.g. `sudo cat /dev/sdXX > /some/where/else.img`
3. Run `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdXX` - hopefully the directory will be recovered.
4. If it doesn't or you face further issues, please try using R-Studio Undelete which is one of the most powerful recovery tools out there.